# What are the deployment tools used in hybrid cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, openstack, rackspace-cloud

I want to setup hybrid cloud and choose OpenStack as private cloud and AWS,RackSpace OpenStack as public clouds. what tools I need to choose for the automatic provisioning and configuration of cloud resources.

thanks

Comment: Are you looking for one tool/solution that could cover all of the different cloud providers or more for specific tools best for each and every provider?

Comment: What language do you want to work in? Do you just want command line tools? There are several OpenStack SDKs that work across OpenStack+Rackspace.

Comment: I want to use Java sdk.before selecting a cloud we need to check the load,monitor and choose one cloud instance(VM) for our application deploye and running.For that, how to check with tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several tools that could help you with provisioning, management, deployment and post deployment support such as Rightscale, Scalr and Xervmon. Xervmon is one tool you should give it a try. It supports multi cloud provisioning, management, deployment and monitoring of these wide array of assets. XOPS - Xervmon Operation Center is an integrated tool that leverages puppet classes to provision and automate routine tasks across multi cloud providers.

Xervmon takes an integrated approach to the whole gamut of cloud management, monitoring across hybrid infrastructure. [Xervmon](https://www.xervmon.com/product-0)